# doubts about resize a virtual disk

Tags: virtualbox

I have a dynamic virtual disk has in a firt time has 5GB of virtual space, and this is the space that I can see when I go to properties of my drive (the virtual SO is wnidows XP).

I resize it with vboxmanage to 15GB, but when I start the virtual machine, in the properties of the drive I can see the same space, 5GB in total.

the new space is an alloacated partition? If this is true, how can I merge all the partitions of the virtual disk in one partition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Linux i resize my ( Win-VM ) partition on this way.

**1) resize the vdi in commandline \ bash**

```
VBoxManage modifyhd path/yourVMImage.vdi --resize 30000
```

*( --resize, command to change the capacity in Megabyte )*
*( works only for VDI and VHD formats )*

**2) after this you have to extend your partition with an partition manager like gparted-live [download it here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/)**

**2.1) you have to start your virtual-machine with these live tool, then you can expand your partition using gparted-live.**

2.1.1) for booting from gparted-live, you have to add another virtual hard disk, 
follow the steps described [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-storage)

> To add another virtual hard disk, or a CD/DVD or floppy drive, select
>   the storage controller to which it should be added (IDE, SATA, SCSI,
>   SAS, floppy controller) and then click on the "add disk" button below
>   the tree. You can then either select "Add CD/DVD device" or "Add Hard
>   Disk". (If you clicked on a floppy controller, you can add a floppy
>   drive instead.) Alternatively, right-click on the storage controller
>   and select a menu item there.
>
> On the right part of the window, you can then set the following:
>
> ...You can select which image file to use.

Comment: read about [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html), on section "8.23. VBoxManage modifyhd"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the new size is an unllocated partition that must be merge with the existing partition. To do it it can be use any partition manager application.

Answer (score 0):

If your filesystem is using LVM. The final steps will be easy:

1. lvextend /dev/vg_nile/lv_root /dev/sda2;
   #assuming vg_nile the name of virtual group, lv_root the logical volume and /dev/sda2 the new added partitions
2. resize2fs /dev/vg_nile/lv_root